# Javascript: In closures, can private members (var`s) be added after instantiation?

Tags: javascript, closures

Can "private" members (vars) be added to a closure after instantiation?

I think I understand this much in my Closure below (please correct me if I'm wrong!):

- `this.x` is available "publicly"
- `var y` is unavailable publicly, but can be accessed through this.y()
- After `new Closure()`, I can add a new "public" like this:

  ```
  var c=new Closure();
  c['z']=25;
  console.log(c.z);  // z is a dynamically added public member
  ```

**So...Is there a way to dynamically add a private member (var) and its get/set function after "new-ing" the Closure?**

```
var Closure=( function(){

    function Closure(x){
        // "public" member
        this.x=x;
    };

    // "private" member backing variable
    var _y=0;

    // get/set private member
    Closure.prototype.y=function(newValue){
        if(newValue){
            _y=newValue;
            return(this);
        }else{
            return(_y);
        }
    };

    // return
    return(Closure);

} )();


var c=new Closure(10,15);

// Can I add var _z and it's get/set function at this point?
```

Comment: Yes you can. Just create a new closure and add the getter/setter functions of the private variable on the object. However the new private variable will only be in the new closure. It won't be in the old closure. Anyway, what's your use case?

Comment: @AaditMShah. Thanks for responding! So how would I dynamically add `var z` to Closure at runtime (pardon my "noobiness")?  I would describe my use-case as "dynamic inheritance".  I want to start with a base Closure and dynamically add members (public & private) as needed.

Comment: I would do something like `(function (c, z) { c.z = function (v) { if (arguments.length) { z = v; return c; } else return z; }; }(c, null))`. However, do you really need private variables? Consider: you're already letting programmers get and set the value of `z` using getters and setters. So why not make it public instead? Furthermore, inheritance and OOP is not the solution for 99% of use-cases. You should take a look at algebraic data types instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `var y` is unavailable publicly

Yes

> but can be accessed through `this.y()`

No. `this` is usually an object, and `.y` is always a *property* reference. It can never be used to access the `y` *variable*.

> Is there a way to dynamically add a private member (var) and its get/set function after "new-ing" the Closure?

No. When the `Closure()` function has been called (in your case as a constructor), its scope with all the variables (`x`) is settled and cannot be modified.

The same thing holds for that IIFE, whose execution introduced the local `Closure` and `_y` variables that are afterwards settled.

What you can do however is to add a *new* getter/setter pair that has its own scope (where it might have additional "private" variables), but it is impossible to access the `_y` variable or manipulate the scope it is located in from outside.

```
function Scope(x, y) {
    // "public" member
    this.x = x;

    // private "member"
    var _y = y;

    // accessors:
    this.setY = function(newValue) { _y = newValue; };
    this.getY = function() { return  _y; };
    // '_y' is still accessible here ^^
    // through closure of the two functions, which can access their parent scope
}
var c = new Scope(10, 15);
c.x // 10
c.getY() // 15
```

There is no way here to modify the scope in which `_y` (and `x` and `y`) reside. However, we can add a new field to `c`, even if its variable will not live in the same scope:

```
function addZ(obj, z) {
    // new scope, private variable:
    var _z = z;

    obj.getZ = function() { return _z; }
    // setter analogous if you want one
}
addZ(c, 12);
c.getZ() // 12
```

Comment: Not true, if those private variables are data structures and you provide accessor methods with access to the closure it works fine. You can also use `eval()` to cheat lexical scope. Whether or not you __should__ do either of those things is another matter.

Comment: @JaredSmith: A variable is not a data structure, it's a *variable*. Sure, if it holds a structure you might be able to *modify* that structure, but you cannot access/set the *variable* without an explicit closure that allows you to do so. `eval` could be used for many interesting things, but you cannot use it to modify already existing scopes (except the "current", but that's not interesting)

Comment: I see...so Closure will not accept new `var`s after instantiation.  So to imitate dynamically added vars, would you endorse the concept of a private object literal that holds key-value pairs. When a new "private" is needed, just push a new key-value on the private object literal and have a getter/setter that fetches any specified key-value. This would be similar to the ViewBag in asp.net MVC.  Or is there a more preferred way?

Comment: @JustAsking: Well, usually you don't need private fields dynamically - especially if there is nothing that uses them. If you want to create new accessors for them though, you can just create a new private variable for them - it doesn't need to be bound to the scope created by the constructor function. I've updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sort of. You can make a private object or array and provide methods to add to it.

using a `WeakMap`:

```
function myClosure() {
    var hidden = new WeakMap();
    var obj = {
        addPrivate: function(name, value) {
            var privateData = hidden.get(this);
            privateData[name] = value;
        }
    }
    hidden.set(obj, {});
    return obj;
}

var foo = myClosure();
foo.addPrivate('bar', 7);
foo.getBar = function() {
    var priv = hidden.get(this);
    return priv.bar;
}
foo.getBar(); //7
```

A better question is should you do this? The answer is generally no. The only time I consider it worth the inconvenience of all of the above chichanery is when I have an application core object that I progressively enhance with asynchronous extension scripts (I use the `WeakMap` form if I don't need to worry about older browsers, if I do I use nested obj literals).

Comment: Your first snippet gets me a `Syntax Error: at index 1 in "(var bar = 7);": expected expression, got keyword 'var'`

Comment: Even if you fix that, this will either create a *global* `bar` variable, or your `getBar` function does not work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The `bar` you created exists in the scope of `addPrivate`, *not* in `myClosure`. And neither of those scope is accessible to your `getBar` function - which should throw a reference error. If it doesn't, it means that you have a global `bar` lying around; please try again with a clean global scope.

Comment: I deleted my comment as you are correct. Apologies. Updating answer.